# How to get 'On hold' suffix removed

Tags: support, close-reasons

My first question was put 'on hold' due to some errors. Now that I have fixed them, how can I get that suffix removed?

Comment: It might be a good idea to edit this post and include the [link to the original question](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/76274/how-can-i-build-a-nuclear-reactor-in-my-backyard) so that people know what you are talking about and can quickly have a look at the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a question doesn't seem to fit the sites guidelines as written in the [help center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) the community will put it on hold to allow you to edit it, so that it fits the sites guidelines.

If we wouldn't put it on hold someone could answer it, although the question doesn't fit the guidelines. If the question is then edited the answer can be invalidated. This would be bad.

After some edits your question will be put into a review-queue to determine whether it's okay or not. There people can vote again to reopen the question. Your goal should be to listen to the people and fix the question. After that it can be reopened. If you edited your question and nothing happens for some time it's a good idea to make a Meta Post (like you just did) and go to the chat to ask for assistance.

See also [What does it mean if my question is "closed" or "on hold"?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) in the help center for more information.